# Using primary key of a table as foreign key in insert query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to populate data into my tables. Let's say I have three tables

```
TABLE_A, TABLE_B, TABLE_C.
```

`TABLE_A` has four columns, I am currently getting values for this table as follows:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A(COL_A, COL_B, COL_C, COL_D) 
    SELECT TABLE_A.SQ.nextval, colb AS COL_B, colc AS COL_C, cold as COL_D 
    FROM TABLE_D
```

Now I want to use the primary key of `Table_A` as foreign key in my other table which is `TABLE_B`, and primary key of `TABLE_B` as foreign key of `TABLE_C`.

The Use case is as follows I want to extract data from a table(TableX) and load it into other tables (TABLE_A, Table_Y, TABLE_Z), we have normalized TableX to three tables, and since i cannot definitely use the primary key of old table i am using sequence to generate Primary Key.

Comment: If you implement some `ETL` process you may also ask: 1) do I need sequences at all? 2) can I use the *natural key* to lookup the *surrogate primary key* of the parent table? You should anyway describe your use case more detailed...

Comment: Hi @MarmiteBomber I have updated the post with the Use Case

Answer (score 2):

The `RETURNING INTO` clause can be used for this. Below is a simple example for a single row insert with tablea, tableb and tablec.

Note that this is is for a row by row operation, so you'd have to loop through table_d in your case. There is a `RETURNING BULK COLLECT INTO` as well to populate an array.

```
create sequence tablea_seq;
create sequence tableb_seq;
create sequence tablec_seq;


create table tablea (
    tablea_id                      number 
                                   constraint tablea_tablea_id_pk primary key,
    c1                             varchar2(10 char)
)
;

create table tableb (
    tablea_id                      number
                                   constraint tableb_tablea_id_fk
                                   references tablea on delete cascade,
    tableb_id                      number 
                                   constraint tableb_tableb_id_pk primary key,
    col1                           varchar2(10 char)
);

create table tablec (
    tableb_id                      number
                                   constraint tablec_tableb_id_fk
                                   references tableb on delete cascade,
    tablec_id                      number 
                                   constraint tablec_tablec_id_pk primary key,
    col1                           varchar2(10 char)
);

DECLARE
  l_tablea_id tablea.tablea_id%TYPE;
  l_tableb_id tableb.tableb_id%TYPE;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO tablea (tablea_id,c1) VALUES (tablea_seq.NEXTVAL,'some val')
    RETURNING tablea_id INTO l_tablea_id;
  INSERT INTO tableb (tableb_id,tablea_id,col1)
    VALUES (tableb_seq.NEXTVAL,l_tablea_id,'Foobar')
    RETURNING tableb_id INTO l_tableb_id;
  INSERT INTO tablec (tablec_id,tableb_id,col1)
    VALUES (tableb_seq.NEXTVAL,l_tablea_id,'Foobar');
END;
/
```

Comment: Great Example Koen, can i use Select instead of Values, I mean 
 INSERT INTO tablea (tablea_id,c1) VALUES (tablea_seq.NEXTVAL,'some val')
    RETURNING tablea_id INTO l_tablea_id;
  INSERT INTO tableb (tableb_id,tablea_id,col1)
    VALUES(SELECT table_Id from table_D) , l_tablea_id,'Foobar')
    RETURNING tableb_id INTO l_tableb_id;
END:

But now lets say i have more column, then what do i in that case.

Comment: If you do ```SELECT ... FROM``` instead of values how do you want to handle the next insert ? Say you insert 10 rows in table_a, which primary key value from a will you assign to each row in b ? Unless you give me a very detailed requirement, I can't answer that question. But you'll definitely need the ```BULK COLLECT INTO``` when you insert multiple rows in a single statement.

Answer (score 0):

In the same operation? If so, then you wouldn't directly use sequence value, but first store it into a local variable so that you could use it as a

- primary key for `table_a`
- foreign key value while inserting into `table_b`

The same goes for `table_b`'s primary key (which will then be used as a foreign key in `table_c`).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is your *denormalized* `table_x` consisting of three *parent -child* levels, where `key_n` is th e*original key of the level `n` and `col_n` their respective attribute.

```
select * from table_x;
 
     KEY_1 COL_1           KEY_2 COL_2           KEY_3 COL_3     
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       100 a                 101 aa                101 aaa       
       100 a                 101 aa                102 aab       
       100 a                 102 ab                103 aba       
       100 a                 102 ab                104 abb       
       200 b                 103 ba                105 baa       
       200 b                 103 ba                106 bab       
       200 b                 104 bb                107 bba       
       200 b                 104 bb                108 bbb
```

With some *analytic functions* you may identify which row are to be inserted on which level and assign the new primary keys.

Here

- on level `n` insert only row with `lev_n_rn = 1`
- the new `ID`s are assigned sequentially with `row_number` (without a sequence)

.

```
with norm as (
select  
 row_number() over (partition by KEY_1 order by KEY_2, KEY_3) lev_1_rn,
 KEY_1, COL_1, 
 row_number() over (partition by KEY_1,KEY_2 order by  KEY_3) lev_2_rn,
 KEY_2, COL_2,
 row_number() over (partition by KEY_1,KEY_2,KEY_3 order by COL_3) lev_3_rn, 
 KEY_3, COL_3
from table_x)
select
 lev_1_rn,
 sum(case when lev_1_rn = 1 then 1 end) over (order by KEY_1) id1,
 KEY_1, COL_1, 
 lev_2_rn,
 sum(case when lev_2_rn = 1 then 1 end) over (order by KEY_1, KEY_2) id2,
 KEY_2, COL_2,
 lev_3_rn, 
 sum(case when lev_3_rn = 1 then 1 end) over (order by KEY_1, KEY_2, KEY_3) id3,
 KEY_3, COL_3
from norm;

  LEV_1_RN        ID1      KEY_1 COL_1        LEV_2_RN        ID2      KEY_2 COL_2        LEV_3_RN        ID3      KEY_3 COL_3     
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1        100 a                   1          1        101 aa                  1          1        101 aaa       
         2          1        100 a                   2          1        101 aa                  1          2        102 aab       
         3          1        100 a                   1          2        102 ab                  1          3        103 aba       
         4          1        100 a                   2          2        102 ab                  1          4        104 abb       
         1          2        200 b                   1          3        103 ba                  1          5        105 baa       
         2          2        200 b                   2          3        103 ba                  1          6        106 bab       
         3          2        200 b                   1          4        104 bb                  1          7        107 bba       
         4          2        200 b                   2          4        104 bb                  1          8        108 bbb
```

The rest is a task for `INSERT ALL`  using the above query and constraining the relevant rows and attributes (pk + fk) for each level

```
insert all
when LEV_1_RN = 1 then
  into table_a (id, key_1, col_1) values(ID1, KEY_1, COL_1)
when LEV_2_RN = 1 then
  into table_b (id, fk_id,  key_2, col_2) values(ID2, ID1, KEY_2, COL_2) 
when LEV_3_RN = 1 then  
  into table_c (id, fk_id,  key_3, col_3) values(ID3, ID2, KEY_3, COL_3)
with norm as (
select  
 row_number() over (partition by KEY_1 order by KEY_2, KEY_3) lev_1_rn,
 KEY_1, COL_1, 
 row_number() over (partition by KEY_1,KEY_2 order by  KEY_3) lev_2_rn,
 KEY_2, COL_2,
 row_number() over (partition by KEY_1,KEY_2,KEY_3 order by COL_3) lev_3_rn, 
 KEY_3, COL_3
from table_x)
select
 lev_1_rn,
 sum(case when lev_1_rn = 1 then 1 end) over (order by KEY_1) id1,
 KEY_1, COL_1, 
 lev_2_rn,
 sum(case when lev_2_rn = 1 then 1 end) over (order by KEY_1, KEY_2) id2,
 KEY_2, COL_2,
 lev_3_rn, 
 sum(case when lev_3_rn = 1 then 1 end) over (order by KEY_1, KEY_2, KEY_3) id3,
 KEY_3, COL_3
from norm;
```

Producing this result

```
select * from table_a;
        ID      KEY_1 COL_1     
---------- ---------- ----------
         1        100 a         
         2        200 b         

select * from table_b;
        ID      FK_ID      KEY_2 COL_2     
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1        101 aa        
         2          1        102 ab        
         3          2        103 ba        
         4          2        104 bb 
         
select * from table_c;        
        ID      FK_ID      KEY_3 COL_3     
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         2          1        102 aab       
         4          2        104 abb       
         6          3        106 bab       
         8          4        108 bbb
```

I'd assume this will be (for a large table) the most effective transformation (as you ommit loops and lookups).

If you maintain the new table is a signle user mode (no multiuser) you actually *do not need sequences*, but if you like you may deploy them after the transformation with propper set initial values.